# Различие анонимных методов и lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

В чем различие между анонимными методами и lambda-выражениями?

---

В анонимных методах мы можем обойтись без параметров, если даже это и ожидается:

```
public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
...
SomeEvent += delegate { Console.WriteLine("some information") };
```

Какие еще есть плюсы/минусу у анонимных методов и lambda-выражениями?

Comment: в принципе только одно различие - синтаксис: если лямбда не expression, то она тот же самый делегат

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Разница в том, что лямбда, в зависимости от контекста использования, может быть скомпилирована в две совершенно разных вещи:

Если контекст подразумевает использование лямбды как анонимного метода - лямбда компилируется в анонимный метод.

```
Func<int, bool> filter = x => x > 2;
```

будет превращено компилятором в то же, во что он превратит

```
Func<int, bool> filter = delegate(int x) { return x > 2 };
```

Т.е. в этом варианте использования - лямбды - это просто сокращенный вариант старого синтаксиса анонимных методов. Именно в таком виде они внедрены в Java / C++ и остальных языках, которые "добавили лямбды" за последние пару лет.

В той же Java лямбды - это единственный способ объявить анонимный метод. До введения лямбд в Java были анонимные классы (анонимные реализации интерфейсов), но не было анонимных методов - что сделало написание *современного* кода с промисами (аналогом Task) дико неудобным. Введение анонимных методов ("лямбд") значительно упростило написание цепочек тасков с коллбеками.

В C# синтаксис анонимных методов был введен в 2.0, в 2005-ом году, цепочки промисов можно делать уже больше десяти лет, так что что лямбды в качестве альтернативного синтаксиса ключевому слову `delegate` картины не изменили. Вводились лямбды совсем не ради него.

В этом варианте использования различия между лямбдами и `delegate {}` минимальны - на уровне "тут меньше скобок". Никаких принципиальных различий или значительных преимуществ между двумя синтаксисами нет.

---

Если контекст подразумевает использование лямбды в виде значения типа Expression, то лямбда компилируется не в анонимный метод, а объект-композит, представляющий код лямбды в виде AST:

```
Expression<Func<int, bool>> filter = x => x > 2;
```

превращается в

```
ParameterExpression paramX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

Expression<Func<int, bool>> filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
        Expression.GreaterThan(
            paramX, Expression.Constant(2)
            ),
        paramX
    );
```

Такое представление позволяет в рантайме преобразовывать выражения из кода (`x > 2`) в код на другом языке (SQL: `WHERE table.ColumnX > 2`, OData: `$filter=x&gt2`).

Именно из-за этого варианта использования и ввели лямбды в C#, и именно за счет него работают LINQ-провайдеры вроде Entity Framework.

Comment: А не подскажите книги\ресурсы по Expression trees?

Comment: @VladislavKhapin у Джона Скита в "C# in Depth" в девятой главе неплохо описано.

Comment: Вводились лямбды совсем не ради него. В [C# лямбды притащены ради уменьшения дырки между абстракциями repository / query object и обычными коллекциями объектов в памяти.](https://habr.com/en/post/313350/#comment_9885676)

Comment: @AK на то время был реально один провайдер, так что это по сути одно и то же :))